# $3f(x) + f(2-x) = (x)^2 , f(x)=$?

Tags: functions

$3f(x) + f(2-x) = (x)^2 , f(x)=$?

I saw someone solved it like this:
She first takes that $x = u$, then equation looks like this $3f(u) + f(2-u) = (u)^2$
Then she takes that $x = 2-u$, then equation looks like this $3f(2-u) + f(u) = (2-u)^2$
Then she solves these two equations like system, and finally she gets that $f(x) = [x^2 + 2x -2] / 4$

But I'm confused with this method. First she takes that $x = u$, then she takes that $x = (2-u)$ and then she merges these two in system, how's that possible that $x$ can be two things at same time?

Comment: The idea is that the functional equation must be true no matter what we take for $x$.  For example, taking $x=0$ tells us that $3f(0)+f(2)=0$ and taking $x=2$ tells us that $3f(2)+f(0)=4$.   You can now use those two equations to find $f(0),f(2)$.  This works for all $x$.  To gain intuition, find $f(1)$ this way, and so on.

Comment: Also $4f(1)=1\to f(1)=\frac14$

Comment: @lulu Thanks a lot! From pile of tasks I worked, I just confused with this one.. 
Thanks again..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably assumed that the relation holds for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

For example the relation holds for $x=8$ which implies
$$ 3 f(8) + f(-6) = 64 $$
Moreover, the relation also holds for $x=-6$ which implies
$$ 3 f(-6) + f(8) = 36 $$
It's not too difficult now to solve for $f(8)$ and $f(-6)$ in this case by looking at the induced linear system.

In general you could just fill in $x=u$ as an example and you could fill in $x=2-u$ in the equation just as I did above in my short example.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

After replecing $x$ in $3f\left( x \right) +f\left( 2-x \right) ={ x }^{ 2 }$ with the $2-x$ you will get a new equation $\\ 3f\left( 2-x \right) +f\left( x \right) ={ \left( 2-x \right)  }^{ 2 }\\ $ then you can solve two system equations $$\\ \\ \begin{cases} 3f\left( x \right) +f\left( 2-x \right) ={ x }^{ 2 } \\ 3f\left( 2-x \right) +f\left( x \right) ={ \left( 2-x \right)  }^{ 2 } \end{cases}\Rightarrow \begin{cases} -9f\left( x \right) -3f\left( 2-x \right) =-3{ x }^{ 2 } \\ 3f\left( 2-x \right) +f\left( x \right) ={ \left( 2-x \right)  }^{ 2 } \end{cases}\Rightarrow f\left( x \right) =\frac { { x }^{ 2 }+2x-2 }{ 4 } $$